# Tricky Job with Date Ranges - MS Access/SQL

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I've got a tricky little job to do which involves calculating the overlap between certain date ranges. I've written a bit of code in VBA/Excel which works fine, but it's appallingly slow - and I think this sort of thing belongs in Access (or similar) rather than Excel anyway.

Very brief summary of what needs doing...

Have a main table (could be millions of rows) which looks something like:

## Main_Table

- Account_Number_Index
- Start_Date
- End_Date
- Data_Item_1
- Data_Item_2
  ...
  ...
  ...
- Data_Item_N

I also have a small table of "analysis periods" (typically 4-6 rows only)

## Analysis_Periods

- Period_Index
- Period_Start_Date
- Period_End_Date
- Period_Label

I need to create an output table from all of this which has one record for each combination of Account_Number_Index and Period_Index. Fields would be:

## Output_Table

- Account_Number_Index
- Overlap_Start_Date (explained below)
- Overlap_End_Date (explained below)
- Period_Index
- Period_Lable
- Data_Item_1
- Data_Item_2
  ...
  ...
  ...
- Data_Item_N

So in loose pseudo-code it would look something like this:

```
For each row in Main_Table

    For each row in Analysis_Periods

        Work out the overlapping period (Overlap_Start_Date...Overlap_End_Date) for time intervals (Start_Date...End_Date) and (Period_Start_Date...Period_End_Date)

        If there is no overlap at all

            Do nothing

        Else

            Output a row of data to Output_Table which is identical to the row in the Main_Table except that:
                 * Overlap_Start_Date used instead of Start_Date
                 * Overlap_End_Date used instead of End_Date
                 * Period_Index and Period_Label tagged also output

         End If

    Next row in Analysis_Periods

Next row in Main_Table
```

Working out the overlapping period is just a case of the time interval between:
(a) max(Start_Date, Period_Start_Date)
(b) min(End_Date, Period_End_Date)

I think I've managed to include a hyperlink below to a little scribble on a bit of paper re: overlapping time intervals, if that helps visualise the problem.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of doing this in Access please, either with some SQL code or some VBA (or both)?

I'm not an expert in this stuff so I hope I'm making sense...apologies if not.

Most grateful for any assistance.

Thx
A

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al3pO.jpg

Comment: Can analysis and period index pairs have more than one overlapping date ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a filtered `CROSS JOIN` between both tables where you place tables in comma-separated list in `FROM` clause without any `JOIN` followed by a `WHERE` on dates. Then place query inside a conditional aggregate `GROUP BY` for needed `MIN` and `MAX` on dates.

```
SELECT m.Account_Number_Index, 
       p.Period_Index, 
       MIN(IIF(m.Start_Date < a.Period_Start_Date, 
               m.Start_Date, a.Period_Start_Date)) AS Overlap_Start_Date,
       MAX(IIF(m.End_Date < a.Period_End_Date, 
               a.Period_End_Date, m.End_Date)) As Overlap_End_Date

FROM MainTable m, AnalysisPeriods a
WHERE m.Start_Date <= a.Period_Start_Date 
  AND a.Period_End_Date <= m.End_Date
GROUP BY m.Account_Number_Index, 
         p.Period_Index
```

And in a second query join the original tables to this query on index fields. Even consider building a temp table *overlap_table* (with `SELECT ... INTO` clause) and use in place of query:

```
SELECT m.Account_Number_Index, 
       p.Period_Index, 
       q.Overlap_Start_Date, 
       q.Overlap_End_Date
       p.Period_Label,
       m.Data_Item_1,
       m.Data_Item_2,
       m.Data_Item_3, 
       ...
       m.Data_Item_n

FROM (overlap_query_or_table q
INNER JOIN MainTable m 
  ON q.Account_Number_Index = m.Account_Number_Index)
INNER JOIN AnalysisPeriods a
  ON q.Period_Index = p.Period_Index
```

**NOTE**: This processing involves the cross join which returns the cartesian product between both tables (i.e., ~1 million rows X 5-6 rows) so efficiency is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. I've been able to create a cross join using the expression builder in Access (I'd never heard of a cross join until last night!). I should be able to tweak the query to do the time overlap calcs for every row in the big new table and I think I'll be done.

Comment: So did this answer work or not? Any errors? Undesired results? Technically this is not a true cross join since we use a `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If using access, why don't you use a join query?
Something alike

```
Select m.Account_Number_Index, m.Start_Date,m.End_Date, ap.Period_Index, ap.Period_Lable,
m.Data_Item_1, m.Data_Item_2 ... ... ... m.Data_Item_N
From Analysis_Periods as ap left join Main_Table as m on (m.Start_Date >= ap.Period_Start_Date and m.End_date <= ap.Period_End_Date)
```

For the correct overlap start and end use the function iif.